# Showing $nl(ST) ≥ nl(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Suppose that $U, V, W$ are finitely generated vector spaces, with $T ∈ L(U, V )$ and $S ∈ L(V, W)$.

a) Show that $nl(ST) ≥ nl(T)$.

b) Show that $rk(ST) ≤ rk(S)$.

c) Show that $rk(ST) ≤ rk(T)$.

d) Show that $nl(ST) ≥ nl(S) + dim(U) − dim(V )$.

I can use the rank-nullity theorem, but I need to show at least 2 of these directly before. I'm having a hard time working these out.

a) Show that $nl(ST) ≥ nl(T)$.

So, $dim(ker(ST))≥dim(ker(T))$

Now, $ker(ST)$ = {$x: S(T(x)) = 0$}

And I get stuck here...

$ker(T) =$ {$x: T(x) = 0$}.

And $S(T(x)) = 0$, so for $T(x) = 0$, $S(0)= 0$, so $ker(T)$ is in $ker(ST)$.

So, $ker(T)$ <= $ker(ST)$. And so $ dim(ker(ST))≥dim(ker(T))$.

That's what I got for the first one. Can I get some feedback and help on the others?

Thanks!

Comment: For part a, show that $\ker (T) \subset \ker (ST)$

Comment: For part c, it is helpful to consider the transpose of $ST$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I tried to do that for part a, did I do it wrong? and is it possible to show it without transpose?

Comment: Note that the inequality for d can be written as
$$
\dim V - \operatorname{nl} S \geq \dim U - \operatorname{nl}(ST).
$$

Comment: Oh, I stopped reading after "I got stuck here...". You seem to have done part a correctly!

Comment: @BenGrossmann so part a is correct? Yayyyy!

Comment: By the way, $\subseteq$ is `\subseteq`.

Comment: Can you see how to do part c with the rank nullity theorem?

Comment: Part b you can actually do directly by considering the images of $ST$ and $S$ in the same way that you considered the kernels of $ST$ and $T$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann for part b: here's what I got:
$im(ST) =${$y:y= S(T(x))$} And let $T(x) = v$, so $im(ST) =${$y:y= S(v)$} And since $v $ is in space $V$, and $S$ maps from $V$ to $W$, have that $im(T)$ is in $im(ST)$? I feel like this seems a bit weak?

Comment: You have the right idea, but you could say it a bit more clearly

Comment: @BenGrossmann what if I start with $im(T) =$ {$v: T(x) = v$} for $v$ of $V$ and $x$ of $U$. 
So $S(T(x)) = S(v)$ in $W$. So, $im(ST) =${$y: S(v) = y$}, for $y$ in $W$. so $im(ST) =${$y: S((T(x)) = y$}. So $im(T)$ $\subseteq$  $im(ST)$

Comment: Actually, I misspoke earlier: it is b that can be shown directly, not c. Part c can be done with the rank-nullity theorem. It necessarily holds that $\operatorname{im}(ST) \subset \operatorname{im}(S)$, but not necessarily $\operatorname{im}(ST) \subset \operatorname{im}(T)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm having a hard time with c) and d). I seem to get to a point in c) where $dimV - nl(ST) <= dimU -nl(T)$, and from part a), we know $nl(ST)>=nl(T)$, but does that mean $dimV - nl(ST) <= dimU -nl(T)$ is true? Don't we need to know what $dimV$ and $dimU$ are for this? And how does this help show what part c) is asking? I'm having a similar problem with part d)

Answer (score 1):

**Part a:**

We note that $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(ST)$. Indeed, suppose that $u \in U$ is an element of $\ker(T)$. By definition, it follows that $T(v) = 0$. Thus, $S(T(v)) = S(0) = 0$. Thus, $v \in \ker(ST)$. With that, we can conclude that $\dim \ker (T) \leq \dim \ker (ST)$, as desired.

**Part b:**

We note that $\operatorname{im}(ST) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(S)$. Indeed, suppose that $w$ is an element of $\operatorname{im}(ST)$. By definition, this means that there is an element $u \in U$ such that $w = S(T(u))$. Thus, the element $v = T(u) \in V$ is such that $w = S(v)$. It follows that $w \in \operatorname{im}(S)$. With that, we can conclude that $\dim \operatorname{im}(ST) \leq \dim \operatorname{im}(S)$, as desired.

**Part c:**

Apply part a and the rank nullity theorem.
$$
\operatorname{rk}(ST) = \dim(U) - \operatorname{nl}(ST) \leq \dim(U) - \operatorname{nl}(T) = \operatorname{rk}(T).
$$

**Part d:**

Applying the rank-nullity theorem to the inequality from part b yields
$$
\dim V - \operatorname{nl} S \geq \dim U - \operatorname{nl}(ST).
$$
Solving this inequality for $\operatorname{nl}(ST)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: why is $rk(ST) = dim(U)−nl(ST)$? I thought it was $rk(ST) +nl(ST) = dim(V)$?

Comment: @eddie The space whose dimension is used in the rank-nullity theorem is the domain of the map. $ST$ is a linear map from $U$ to $W$. We have $\operatorname{rk}(S) + \operatorname{nl}(S) = \dim V$ because $S$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$.

Comment: THANKS!!!! I solved it but got stuck because of that. Greatly appreciate all the help!!!